# How to integrate Element plus with Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui, element-plus

I'm trying to install element plus with Nuxt 3. I tried the official documentation for element plus, [Element plus docs](https://element-plus.org/en-US/guide/quickstart.html#on-demand-import). I installed `unplugin-vue-components` `unplugin-auto-import` and added the specified webpack settings in the nuxt config file(under the webpack section), but I couldn't use any of the element plus components. I also saw the using Nuxt.js part in the docs but I couldn't understand it. Can anyone point me to the correct resources? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can have a try with this starter
https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus-nuxt-starter
works fine on my node 16

Answer (score 0):

We can integrate the element-plus UI with Nuxt 3 easily. Below are a few steps for the same.
I have used the node `v19.3.0`

**plugins/element-ui.js**

```js
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ElementPlus)
})
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
   alias: {
        'element-plus/dist/index.css': resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/element-plus/dist/index.css'),
        'element-plus': resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/element-plus/dist/index.full.js'),
    },
    plugins: ['~/plugins/element-ui'],
    vite: {
        optimizeDeps: {
            include: ['element-plus'],
        },
    },
})
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "element-plus": "^2.2.27"
  }
}
```